# Sequentially filescraping text files - a smarter way?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to scrape some text files into a DB - the format is similar to this with a couple of 1000 segments like this :

```
Posted By
Date
John Keys
31.08.2019, 10:10 AM
Peter Hall 200 150
Ed Parker 14 1
Posted By
Date
John Keys
31.08.2019, 10:15 AM
Rose Stone 200 150
Travis Anderson 14 1
```

The records that are important are the records that are coming right after "Date" - so the logic is :

```
inside_match_flag =0
for line in ins:
   if inside_match_flag == 1:
      inside_match_flag = 2        # add one to it as we will get all lines 
   if line == "Posted By":         # until we see Posted By again (or EOF)
      inside_match_flag =0         # we are now outside the segment
   if line == "Date" :             # lines after Dates are the ones we want
      inside_match_flag =1         # the following lines are to be stored
```

So this is the way I've done it (the above is not the running code) before doing this by keeping track of a flag and depending on the flag_value I know what lines are most likely coming next.

The issue is of course this about 'the lines coming next' - as I'm reading line per line, I can't easy grab out these segments as I don't want to rely on loading the complete file into memory (as it can go huge).

But the code always gets ugly when I implement something like this - and thinking anyone here that would have a lot smarter approach to do this ?

And note - I am also interested if there would be a super-smart compact way to do this if it requires to load all into memory where code doesn't get so ugly, if all is in memory I guess I can just look for DATE field and save all lines between until it sees Posted By again.

### Edit 1

Note the number of players can be more than 2 per game, so a record could also look like this :

```
Posted By
Date
John Keys
31.08.2019, 10:10 AM
Peter Hall 200 150
Ed Parker 54 1
Rose Stone 20 15
Travis Anderson 1 150
Posted By
...
....
```

My dream format would be to have an object like this - example based on the match above with 4 players :

```
{
"Game 1:"
{
 "posted by" : "john keys"
  "date" : "31.08.2019, 10:10 AM"
  "players" : {
               { 1, "Peter Hall, "200", "150" }
               { 2, Ed Parker, "54", "1" }
               { 3 , Rose Stone, "20", "15" }
               { 4, Travis Anderson, "1", "150" }
             }
 }
}
```

Note : not 100% correct json format there - and doesn't have to be json, just an object as I will throw them into a SQLite database where it's stored per game which should be illustrated above.

Comment: Are there always be only 4 data lines of interest for each section?

Comment: no, the part with the names and numbers are scores - and these games can be anything from 2 players to 10 players - so the amount of players per game will change. But all relevant data will be between "Date" and the next "Posted By" (or EOF)

Comment: post the expected formatted output/records for posted 2 sections (from question)

Comment: ive added an edit with how i woud like to extract them ( pseudo json sorry ) but i will store them per game in sqlite in the end

Comment: @MdTp Why don't you use regular expressions to solve your problem ??

Comment: is there any reasonable assumption on how long a single record could be, in bytes?

Comment: though, it's unclear how `"Game 1:"` is composed - the ordinal number of segment?

Comment: "game 1" there would just be the first game-entry - assuming my example in Edit1 is the first game out of many ( in this case game 1 has 4 players )

Comment: @Akshay sapra my regex-kungfu is not even close to sort this one out with regex :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimized and memory-efficient *generator* function approach which yields records *on demand*:

```
import pprint

def extract_records(fname):
    def prepare_record(rec):
        return {'posted by': rec[0], 'date': rec[1],
                'players': [[i] + p.rsplit(maxsplit=2)
                            for i, p in enumerate(rec[2:], 1)]}

    with open(fname) as f:
        record = []
        add_item = False
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if line == 'Date':
                add_item = True
                continue
            elif line == 'Posted By':
                add_item = False
                if record:
                    yield prepare_record(record)
                    record = []
                    continue
            if add_item:
                record.append(line)
        if record:
            yield prepare_record(record)


records_gen = extract_records('datafile.txt')   # generator
for rec in records_gen:
    pprint.pprint(rec)   #  further processing, ex. inserting into DB
```

The output (2 sample records):

```
{'date': '31.08.2019, 10:10 AM',
 'players': [[1, 'Peter Hall', '200', '150'],
             [2, 'Ed Parker', '14', '1'],
             [3, 'Rose Stone', '20', '15'],
             [4, 'Travis Anderson', '1', '150']],
 'posted by': 'John Keys'}
{'date': '31.08.2019, 10:15 AM',
 'players': [[1, 'Rose Stone', '200', '150'],
             [2, 'Travis Anderson', '14', '1']],
 'posted by': 'John Keys'}
```

Comment: awesome, working well and the yeld and pprint was a nice new addition to look at. One little problem here - some of the names have 3 names, not only first and lastname :( - that one is difficult as i wont be able to use 'space' as field seperator between name and number - i would somehow need to say "grab name until it meets a number" ?

Comment: @MdTp, no problem, assuming that each player can have 2 game marks, see my update with a new output (and your player's name can have any numbers of words :))

Comment: thanks so much, here it became abit python-magic to me how that works - but it does :D cool !

Comment: @MdTp, you're welcome. The change was `p.rsplit(maxsplit=2)` which splits the line by last 2 whitespaces

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic method for this specific case. Here is an example solution:

```
buf_size = ...
start_marker = "Posted by\n"
date_marker = "Date\n"

def parse_game(filename)
    fh = open(filename)
    page = ""
    buffer = True  # just the start value
    while buffer:
        buffer = fh.read(buf_size)
        page += buffer
        records = page.split(start_marker)
        if buffer:
            page = records.pop()
        for record in records:
            # skip everything before "Date" and split by lines
            chunks = record.split(date_marker, 1)[-1].split("\n")
            posted_by, date = chunks[:2]
            players = [chunk.split() for chunk in chunks[2:]]
            yield {
                "posted_by": posted_by,
                "date": date,
                "players": players
            }
```

If you can read the whole file into memory, it will be just:

```
def read_game(filename):
    for record in open(filename).read().split(start_marker):
        # skip everything before "Date" and split by lines
        chunks = record.split(date_marker, 1)[-1].split("\n")
        posted_by, date = chunks[:2]
        players = [chunk.split() for chunk in chunks[2:]]
        yield {
            "posted_by": posted_by,
            "date": date,
            "players": players
        }
```

This solution is very similar to Roman's. It is slightly less memory efficient (assuming you have buf_size of memory), but will result in less IO

Comment: thanks alot - the in memory is absolutely the most pretty but just cant rely on it as these files can get really really huge ( later on i will be looking into reading buffers of bytes and then position back and forth in the file - but that is not on the table now as they are still pretty small )